# I need draggable markers in google maps

Tags: google-maps

I need draggable markers in google maps..

so I changed the code

```
var point = new GLatLng(app.entries[id].data.lat,app.entries[id].data.lng);

var m = new GMarker(point,app.icon[app.entries[id].data.icon]);
```

to

```
var point = new GLatLng(app.entries[id].data.lat,app.entries[id].data.lng);

var m = new GMarker(point,{draggable: true});
```

how can i find the new position of marker..

Comment: Could you provide some actual code to get a grip on the context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are missing listeners as explained in the documentation.

Please take a look at this sample:

```
var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
var center = new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419);
map.setCenter(center, 13);

var marker = new GMarker(center, {draggable: true});

GEvent.addListener(marker, "dragstart", function() {
  map.closeInfoWindow();
  });

GEvent.addListener(marker, "dragend", function() {
  marker.openInfoWindowHtml("Just bouncing along...");
  });

// to get the point of dragger.
GEvent.addListener(markerD2, "drag", function(){
  document.getElementById("location").value=marker.getPoint().toUrlValue();
});


map.addOverlay(marker);
```

Works great here - http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/overlays.html#Draggable_Markers

Comment: After dragging i have to get that position to store that new position of marker..can you help me?

Comment: @Ashitha please [this example](http://koti.mbnet.fi/ojalesa/exam/draggable.html). You can get the value from `marker.getPoint().toUrlValue();`

Comment: code is.. var point = new GLatLng(app.entries[id].data.lat,app.entries[id].data.lng);var m = new GMarker(point,{draggable: true});GEvent.addListener(m, "drag", function(){
  document.getElementById("point").value=m.getPoint().toUrlValue();
});

       m.entry_id = id;
       m.isMarker = true;
       app.entries[id].marker = m;

Comment: @Ashitha did you see this link: http://koti.mbnet.fi/ojalesa/exam/draggable.html that I had posted in the comment.

Comment: I saw that..in my site when i am refreshing the page marker appears in old position

Comment: dragging is now possible..only problem in is storing the new position..when page refreshes marker appers in old position

Comment: That means, you were able to get the points? from the marker & not able to position it when someone refreshes the page.

Comment: I think you need to store the points in a table & when user refresh the page, just read the table and populate the markers like `var center = new GLatLng(<?php echo $point1; ?>, <?php echo $point2; ?>);var marker = new GMarker(center, {draggable: true});`

Comment: even if i change the position of a marker,after the page refreshing marker appears in old position